# Image Borders & Corners C++

Tags: c++, image, opencv

I'm working on openCV C++ project ,

Part of my project requires to point at any pixel of image with my mouse, get it's x, and y coordinates then I should copy a 8*8 Block of pixels around this pixel to apply some image processing functions for this block.

This is a part of my code that take 8*8 block around pixel:

```
cv::Mat foo = Mat(8, 8, CV_8UC3);
foo = img3.colRange(x-4, x + 4).rowRange(y-4, y + 4);
```

But now I have a problem with image borders; if the mouse on a pixel near one of image borders or corners I have an exception because the range of col & rows (The Block size becomes bigger than existing  image).

How can I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just clamp the x and y values so that there are always 4 pixels around them:

```
x = max(4, min(img3.cols - 5, x))
y = max(4, min(img3.rows - 5, x))

cv::Mat foo = img3.colRange(x-4, x + 4).rowRange(y-4, y + 4);
```